# Parabolic Sobolev inequality in Sobolev mixed norm spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, interpolation

Assume $p,q\in (1,\infty)$, $r\in [p,\infty)$, $s\in [q,\infty)$ and
$$
1<\frac{d}{p}+\frac{2}{q}=1+\frac{d}{r}+\frac{2}{s}. 
$$
Let $u\in C_c^\infty((0,1)\times B_1)$, where $B_1=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d|\  |x|<1\}$.

I was wondering whether the following inequality is correct?
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u\|_{L^s_tL^r_x} \leq C(d, p, q, r,s) \left( \|\partial_t u\|_{L^q_tL^p_x}+ \|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^q_tL^p_x}\right). 
\end{equation}

Remark: I know the above estimate is true if $1<p=q<d+2$ and $r=s=\frac{(d+2)p}{d+2-p}$. I guess the general cases can be obtained by some results in interpolation theory, but I am not familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a proof in Corollary 5.3 in Krylov's *On parabolic Adams's, the Chiarenza-Frasca theorems, and some other results related to parabolic Morrey spaces* ([Link](http://www.aimspress.com/article/doi/10.3934/mine.2023038))

[Here](http://www.aimspress.com/data/article/preview/pdf/62a32789ba35de15514969d5.pdf) is also a link to the PDF of the article.